# How do I make a custom uniform?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I make a custom uniform in [Dwarf Fortress (0.31.10)](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/)?
I want a uniform that allows leather armor, shields, and axes.

Comment: 0.31.10 is out and maintains save compatibility as well as including military fixes. You should update.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `m`ilitary and uniforms (`n`). Choose to create a `N`ew uniform. Use `W`eapon, `S`hield, `H`elmet, `G`loves, `B`oots and `L`eggings to select what your dwarves will wear. It's also possible to choose the material using `M` and the color using `C`. There are also settings to switch whether clothing will be worn over civilian clothes (`r`) or not.

Finally there is a setting to switch if the matches must be exact or not (`m`). If matches are set to be exact and items are not available, the dwarf will train without those items. If the matches are set to be not exact and  items are not available, a dwarf will grab the nearest item possible and train with that.

To apply a uniform, go to the 'Assign `U`niforms' tab. Select a dwarf in a squad you want to wear a uniform and press `enter`. To make the uniform count for the entire squad, press `shift`+`enter`.

Lastly, marksdwarf squads need ammunition to train and fight. Set that up in the 'Ammunition' tab (`f`). Then choose the squad you want to have ammo and add it to their squad and select how much you want. You can change the `M`aterial again, and choose wether they are allowed to use their selected material bolts for `C`ombat or `T`raining.

**Note that the ammunition tab is also the location for your Hunters to select their ammo. If you find that your hunters are using up all your bolts, whilst your marksdwarves are twiddling their fingers in the barracks, unassign the ammo from your hunters**